# Error while building the Android source

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am getting following error while building the android source on Mac OS X 10.7.3 (Lion):

```
host SharedLib: libSR_Recognizer (out/host/darwin-x86/obj/lib/libSR_Recognizer.dylib)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_pushAudioIntoRecognizer", referenced from:
      _SR_RecognizerAdvanceImpl in RecognizerImpl.o
      _detectBeginningOfSpeech in RecognizerImpl.o
  "_generatePatternFromFrame", referenced from:
      _SR_RecognizerAdvanceImpl in RecognizerImpl.o
  "_canPushAudioIntoRecognizer", referenced from:
      _SR_RecognizerAdvanceImpl in RecognizerImpl.o
      _detectBeginningOfSpeech in RecognizerImpl.o
  "_generatePatternFromFrameEOI", referenced from:
      _SR_RecognizerAdvanceImpl in RecognizerImpl.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/lib/libSR_Recognizer.dylib] Error 1
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer finally :)

run make with following options

```
make CC=gcc CXX=g++ -j4
```

Everything will go smooth

Comment: I getting the same error but this doesn't work for me. Could you point me on how you have configured your environment?

Comment: this fix is for mac, which OS you are using?

Comment: Mac OS X Lion, of course. XCode 4.3.2. Followed all the instructions.

Comment: This gets me further along in the build but now I'm getting a similar error:   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "__dyld_func_lookup", referenced from:
      _promoteLocalToGlobal in libSDL.a(SDL_dlcompat.o)
      _dlcompat_init_func in libSDL.a(SDL_dlcompat.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get around this error is do the following:

1. Install gcc-4.2 and g++-4.2: `brew install https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/master/apple-gcc42.rb`
2. Set the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables: `export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 && export CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++-4.2`
3. Then build: `make`

If you need to install homebrew for #1, go to: [Homebrew homepage](https://brew.sh/)

Answer (score 3):

i fixed in this way, my compiler looks happy with this.

```
vi ./external/srec/srec/Recognizer/src/RecognizerImpl.c
```

replace all `PINLINE` with `/*** PINLINE ***/`  - actually remove all of them

Answer (score 1):

The only correct solution is to install XCode 3.*

Comment: The trick is to tell make to use right version of compilers, android code is not c99 standard, xcode expects strict c99 standard code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed from Android master stram - external/srec/portable/include/PortExport.h

```
  #if defined(__APPLE_CC__)
  #if __APPLE_CC__ >= 5621
  #undef PINLINE
  #define PINLINE
  #endif
  #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a known issue in AOSP (Visit http://source.android.com/source/known-issues.html).
Install brew package.

You should create your custom build using

```
lunch full-eng
```

instead of

```
lunch full-userdebug
```

I do not find problem on Android-4.1.2_r1